# Can I run an npm package without the npm run command?

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js

I would like to run the next.js build process directly from the command line without going over the package.json. Is it possible to run it without npm run?

Instead of running `npm run build`

I would like to run `next build` directly on the command line.

Cheers for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting to avoid using npm scripts? You could simply run it with `npx`, i.e. `npx next build`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but isn't this just `npm i -g next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside your project's `node_modules/.bin` directory, you should see an alias for the `next` command. So if you want to run `next build` directly without using `npm`...

Bash:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/next build
```

Windows Command Prompt:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\next.cmd build
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go to package.json and then change the scripts.

"build": "next build",

Comment: As stated, I don't want to use the package.json.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so basically whatever you add at the end of the npm run command gets attached to the npm run command:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "export": "next build && next export -o",
  }
```

Now I can run

```
npm export jane-doe-directory
```

And the application will be exported to that directory.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but this answer doesn't seem to line up with what you was asking.. :_

Comment: Agreed with that, haven't found the solution to that problem so far...